# How to train LGBMClassifier using optuna

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use `lgbm` with `optuna` for a classification task.
Here is my model.

```
from optuna.integration import LightGBMPruningCallback
import optuna.integration.lightgbm as lgbm
import optuna

def objective(trial, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    param_grid = {
        # "device_type": trial.suggest_categorical("device_type", ['gpu']),
        "n_estimators": trial.suggest_categorical("n_estimators", [10000]),
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 0.01, 0.3, log=True),
        "num_leaves": trial.suggest_int("num_leaves", 20, 3000, step=20),
        "max_depth": trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 12), 
        "min_data_in_leaf": trial.suggest_int("min_data_in_leaf", 100, 10000, step=1000),
        "lambda_l1": trial.suggest_int("lambda_l1", 0, 100, step=5),
        "min_gain_to_split": trial.suggest_float("min_gain_to_split", 0, 15),
        "bagging_fraction": trial.suggest_float(
            "bagging_fraction", 0.2, 0.95, step=0.1
        ),
        "bagging_freq": trial.suggest_categorical("bagging_freq", [1]),
        "feature_fraction": trial.suggest_float(
            "feature_fraction", 0.2, 0.95, step=0.1
        ),
        "max_features": trial.suggest_categorical(
            "max_features", choices=["auto", "sqrt", "log2"]
        ),
        "n_jobs": -1,
        "random_state": 1121218,
    }
    
    model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(objective="multiclass", **param_grid)
    model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
        eval_metric="multi_logloss",
        early_stopping_rounds=5,
        callbacks=[
            LightGBMPruningCallback(trial, "multi_logloss")
        ],  # Add a pruning callback
    )
    preds = model.predict_proba(X_test)
    return preds, model
```

I then call the model

```
%%time
study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize", study_name="LGBM Classifier")

func = lambda trial: objective(trial, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

preds, model = study.optimize(func, n_trials=100)
```

But I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__ (no varargs). 
<class 'optuna.integration._lightgbm_tuner.sklearn.LGBMClassifier'> with constructor (self, *args:Any, **kwargs:Any) -> None doesn't  follow this convention.
```

The understand the error, but I'm not sure what the correct way is to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you have to specify your hyper-parameters without using variable length arguments.

Could you try to replace this code :

```
model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(objective="multiclass", **param_grid)
```

With :

```
model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(objective="multiclass", n_estimators=param_grid["n_estimators"], learning_rate=param_grid["learning_rate"], max_depth=param_grid["max_depth"], min_data_in_leaf=param_grid["min_data_in_leaf"],lambda_l1=param_grid["lambda_l1"],min_gain_to_split=param_grid["min_gain_to_split"],bagging_fraction=param_grid["bagging_fraction"],bagging_freq=param_grid["bagging_freq"],feature_fraction=param_grid["feature_fraction"],max_features=param_grid["max_features"],n_jobs=param_grid["n_jobs"],random_state=param_grid["random_state"])
```

Comment: Thank you @Theudbald for your reply. The same error occurs at the line `LightGBMPruningCallback(trial, "multi_logloss")` .

Comment: I have rewritten the `model.fit()` part to `model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)]
    )`

and add the other parameters `"early_stopping_rounds":100,
        "eval_metric": "multi_logloss"` to the parameter list and then use it as the other parameters.`early_stopping_rounds=param_grid["early_stopping_rounds"],
                            eval_metric=param_grid["eval_metric"]`. But still I am getting the same error in the model.fit() part.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce on my side. Could your provide your packages versions and the complete log error ?

Comment: Sure. I am using `lightgbm version 3.3.2`, `optuna version 2.10.0`.
I get exactly the same error as before: `RuntimeError: scikit-learn 
estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature 
of their __init__ (no varargs). <class 'optuna.integration._lightgbm_tuner.sklearn.LGBMClassifier'> 
with constructor (self, *args:Any, **kwargs:Any) -> None doesn't  follow this convention.`